# grunt bower-install of a shimmed bower dependency

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, bower-install

I've bower installed some Git repo that I need for my application and I did it by doing the following:

```
bower install git://github.com/user/cooltool.git --save
grunt bower-install
```

and then I get the following error:

```
cooltool was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "app/bower_components/cooltool" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.
```

are Bower components that are installed straight from a GitHub repo always required to be manually added to my `index.html` file? if not, how do I make it include the script correctly?

The Grunt tasks are all part of the `yo angular-fullstack` scaffolding tool.

The gruntfile's `bower-install` task is the following:

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
'bower-install': {
  app: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
    exclude: ['bootstrap-sass']
  }
},
```

Ultimately, I want the script tag for that cooltool bower component to be injected into my `index.html` in the Bower build:js section:

```
<!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->

    <script ...>

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

After performing running `bower install git://github.com/user/cooltool.git --save`, there was a Bower directory created for it, and inside of that directory is a (hidden) `.bower.json` file, but not a main `bower.json` file:

`.bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "d3-cloud",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "_release": "1.0.5",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v1.0.5",
    "commit": "83eb4128335eacdc0736ab7a6cafbdc2b124f484"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud.git",
  "_target": "~1.0.5",
  "_originalSource": "https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud.git"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code/config for the `bower-install` task in your Gruntfile?

Comment: updated. its weird, i'm not sure how bower-install is responsible for injecting the script tags into build:js / vendor / bower tags

Comment: What's the cooltool library exactly?

Comment: can you show us the bower.json from cooltool?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese i've updated the question with the contents of `.bower.json` (note that it is not a main `bower.json`, there isn't one

Comment: I believe you need a `bower.json` file as well as a `main` property within it in order for the injection to take place.

Comment: @Chris since bower.json wasn't automatically created for it during installation like the rest of the bower packages did, how would I force it to create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you'll install something in this way:

```
bower cache clean
bower install component --save
```

However, if the added repo itself does not establish and bower.json rules for main and ignore, you'll need to add it yourself and check that in.

You'd do that in the following way:

```
1.- Fork the original repository for the component
2.- Add a bower.json file.
3.- Include in this file a 
    "main": ['path/to/file'], 
    "ignore":['array','of','things','to','ignore']
3.-bower install your forked git repo, and it will work
```

Comment: Remember executing bower in the main path of your app!!

Comment: After that, grunt will run your app  with `grunt serve`

Comment: I think the problem is that the d3-cloud repo itself doesn't have a main bower.json file

Comment: did u tried to execute 

`bower cache clean`
`bower uninstall d3-cloud --save`
`bower install d3-cloud --save`

Comment: if after doing that it´s not in your main bower.json dependencies, you must add them manually. But i think it´ll not be necessary

Comment: after doing all of those things, it still was not there.

Comment: chech my last edit. After running that, you will see the dependency adding by itself. I also think that when you are adding a repo manually, it usually does not add directly to your dependencies, but when adding with component name, it´s always added

Comment: are you running the bower install in your main application dir?

Comment: also, you are mis-understanding the problem. the main application's bower.json DOES include d3-cloud. that was never the problem. the problem is that upon running the app, GRUNT cannot add it to the index.html file along with all of the other bower dependencies because it cannot find a main entry... because the d3-cloud has no internal bower.json file

Comment: did u tried deleting the whole directory , installing with the component name, not with the repo url, cleaning cache, and reinstalling?

Comment: whole directory (for the module)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77826/discussion-between-alejandro-teixeira-munoz-and-kristian).